# Spring Web Flow - Any transition keeps refreshing the flow

Tags: spring, spring-webflow

Spring web flow transitions not working at all. only the first view state loads. But on click of any transition states, the flow gets refreshed again and the first view is again loaded. Although, the same flow xml and same setup works fine in my friends machine. How is this possible? The same flow(flow xml) works fine in one system and not the other. has anyone ever faced this type of problem? Any help is greatly appreciated. thanks!!!

```
----------------------------

What I was able to see is that, whenver a transition is triggered, it returns http status 302 rather than 200. Hence it defaults to flow start.

Can anyone help me here pls..
```

Comment: Can you please provide some code and indication of what you have already tried?

Comment: Please post your views as well. It is possible that you are not including required SWF fields in your forms. Also, HTTP code 302 is perfectly OK, SWF uses it to redirect you to the next step in webflow

Comment: In the system that is working fine, the JSESSIONID remains the same(on an event transition). Whereas I'm able to see different JSESSIONID in my system. will that be of any issue?

Comment: Well... yes - there's state (IIRC) that SWF uses. If you're losing your session, this would be a problem. Typically, if you're using localhost for testing, there may be a problem with cookies or session tracking. You may want to look up why... this is typically easy to diagnose from logs or using tools like Fiddler or Firebug.

Answer (score 2):

We were able to figure out the issue. SWF uses **JSESSIONID** for every event. If that cookie is not sent back from browser to server, it assumes there is no valid session and it redirects to first page(flow start). This can be fixed either in code or at container level. JESSIONID cookie should not be HttpOnly. Either this can be done in application server(Websphere in my case, not sure other servers have this option). else, in code to have a filter to get the JSESSIONID cookie and do this cookie.setHttpOnly(false);

Firebug is the best tool to identify these kind of issues i guess. :)

Comment: Yes, I was going to say it sounds like you're using your session. However, it should not be true that the cookies must not be HttpOnly unless you're particularly using JavaScript to navigate. Then, of course, HttpOnly would have to be false.